# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurring When trying to read window from GetWindowText() of user32.dll

Tags: c#, user32

In my application, I am reading the text of a window for the same process. I am using GetWindowText of User32.dll. But when it tries to call the method, I am getting the exception "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in aaaa.exe". Where can I see the exact error. And why I am getting this exception.

My code is as below.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, 
    [Out] StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

EnumDelegate enumfunc = new EnumDelegate(EnumWindowsProc);

private bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr win, int lParam)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    GetWindowText(win, sb, 100);
    if (sb.Length > 0)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us a (reduced) sample exhibiting the exception? This might be some issue with the way that you call `GetWindowText`. Since you want to read the text from a window of the same process, why don't you use the managed API instead?

Comment: @AvidProgrammer: Your code is different from nobugz' sample. You are missing to initialize the `StringBuilder` with an initial capacity and passing exactly that capacity as the value of ` nMaxCount` to the `GetWindowText` function. That should do the trick. If you don't, your string builder object has an empty buffer and GetWindowText fails to write to that (and as a side node for future postings: indent your code by 4 spaces or press the *Format as Code* button, that will make the code nicely formatted).

Comment: @divo : Thanks for pointing the difference. Setting the capacity of string builder and sending the same to the api function did the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting this exception because your GetWindowText() call corrupted the garbage collected heap.  Easy to do when you pass a string instead of a StringBuilder or forget to initialize the StringBuilder.

The Right Way:

```
  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
  private static extern bool GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder buffer, int buflen);
...
  var sb = new StringBuilder(666);
  if (GetWindowText(handle, sb, sb.Capacity)) {
    string txt = sb.ToString();
    //...
  }
```

Comment: I am using the string builder and initialized it also. Only change is I am using charset as CharSet.Auto. Will it be a problem?

Comment: Do you have a reference for your last statement? I've been using GetWindowText successfully to retrieve the caption of out-of-proc HWNDs and according to the remarks section here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520%28VS.85%29.aspx) this should not be a problem either.

Comment: Just this one: *This function cannot retrieve the text of an edit control in another application.*  I'll update my post, thanks.

Comment: @nobugz: Sorry, I was missing that part from the documentation. I was only using GetWindowText to get the caption of other application's main windows which is no problem. Thanks for the hint!